# JSON not returning object

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

**JSON Array not returning object instead returning value**

HI friends i have a scenario wherein the user enters his memberid i do a jquery ajax with memberid and fetch the details related to him and put it in a textbox ,

It was working fine on my server when the code is deployed to other server i'm not getting the result

the code is as shown below

1. createaccount.php

   ```
               <title>Century Club</title>
           <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
           <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>


               <link href="css/century-club.css" rel="stylesheet">



           <script src="js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>


               <script type="text/javascript">


                   function check()
                   {       

                       var mid = $("#memberid").val();


                       var dataString = "mid=" + mid ;

                           $.ajax({  
                               type: "POST",  
                               url: "getdetails2.php",  
                               datatype: 'json',
                               data: dataString,
                               beforeSend: function() 
                               {
                                   $('#process').html($('#status').html());
                               },  
                               success: function(data)
                               {
                                       $('#process').html('');
                                        alert(data);
                                       $.each(data, function (i,member) {
                                           $("#name").val(member.name);

                                       });

                               }   
                           });

                   }//End of SecureLogin 


               </script>

             </head>

             <body>
               <div class="container">


                       <div class="menu">
                       <span class="nav_top"></span>
                       <div class="clr"></div>
                           <nav id="menu-wrap">    

           </nav>
                       </div>
               </div>  

                <div class="container">
                   <div class="register">
                    <div class="row">
                   <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-9">
                        <div class="matter"><div style="clear:both; height:15px;"></div>
               <center><h1>Create New Account</h1></center>
               <div style="clear:both; height:8px;"></div>

                    <div class="join-club">
                       <h4 class="join-heading">Century Club - Create Account <br><span class="legend"><font color="#FF0000"><font class="red"> *</font></font> indicates a mandatory field</span></h4>


               <div align="center" id="status" style="display:none">
                       Just Wait a Moment..</div>
                       <div id="process" class="process"></div>          
           <form id="register" name="register"   method="POST">            
                <table class="join-members" width="100%" style="margin:10px 0 0 0; ">
                   <tbody>

                   <tr>
                       <td width="47%"><span>User Name (Membership Account No.)<font class="red"> *</font></span>
                           <p>(Example : abcd1234)</p>
                       </td>
                       <td colspan="2">
                           <input   type="text" name="memberid" id="memberid"  Maxlength="15"
                           value="<?php if(!empty($memberid)) echo $memberid;?>" autocomplete="off"  style="width: 95%;
                       padding: 6px;" class="email2"  onblur="check();"   /></td>
                   </tr>

                   <tr>
                   <td><span>Name <font class="red"> *</font></span></td>

                       <td colspan="2"><input  type="text" name="name" id="name"  readonly
                       value="<?php if(!empty($name)) echo $name;?>"  class="email"/></td>
                   </tr>

                   <tr>
                       <td >
                       </td>
                       <td colspan="2">  <input type="submit"   name='submit_req' value="Submit" class="button"  style="margin:0"  /> </td>
                   </tr>
                   </tbody>
                </table>
           </form>

                 </div>
               </div>
                   </div>
                   </div>
                       <div class="clr"></div>
                   </div>

                   </div>
                </div>

              </body>
           </html>
   ```

JSon response file getdetails2.php

```
 <?php
    include("connection.php");
    $mid=trim($_POST['mid']);

    $query="Select member_id,member_name,office_number,mobile_number,Residence_number from cm_details where member_id='$mid'";
    $data=mysqli_query($dbc,$query);

    //while loop starts here buddy
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($data))
        {
            $mid=$row[0];
            $mname=$row[1];
            $rows[] = array("name" => $mname);
        }//end of while loop here

    @header("Content-type: application/json");
    echo json_encode($rows);
?>
```

As far as the analysis made it is treating the JSON response as an object in my server where the code works fine  but in the other server it doesnt treate it as an object

And one more error i noticed is

```
 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '182' in
 [{"name":"SRI.M.S.ASHOKKUMAR","mobile":"9845901242","rescode":"080","resnum":"25253602","rescode1":"","resnum1":"","offcode":"","offnum":"","offcode1":"","offnum1":"","mobile1":""}]
```

Thats all i could do guys i feel like JSON is not identified by the server something like that help me guys expecting your answers as soon as possible

Comment: are there any errors present? in console and in php?

Comment: The Uncaught TypeError error, is that coming from the old server or the new server?

Comment: The Uncaught Type error is from the new one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What kind of error / problems are you seeing if any? Also maybe use header instead of @header so that you can see error messages.

have you checked your php version on the server that isnt working?
[json_encode / json_decode](http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.json-encode.php) were introduced in php 5.2.

If that's the problem you might need to use something like [jsonwrapper](http://www.boutell.com/scripts/jsonwrapper.html).

Comment: Hey buddy You made my Day , You Guys Always Rock.

Comment: The Problem was i was using @header and that masked the error as per your suggestion i removed it off and found headers already sent error thereby included ob_start() making output buffering got the right result